# How do I go about refactoring my react application

Tags: reactjs, spring, api, refactoring

I'm new to React JS. I have a need to refactor my react application. Currently I'm making an API call to my Spring backend and I have the following response :-

```
"avgTime": 250.0769,
"minTime": 100.0,
"maxTime": 500.0
```

I currently render these responses in a Card component. I've created a component for each response i.e. `avgTime`, `minTime`, `maxTime` But I'm making the same `API` call in each component. Is this a good practice? How can I reuse my API call in these components.

React Code :-

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const SlowestResponse = props => {
  const { className, ...rest } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const SlowestResponse = 'http://localhost:8080/api/SlowestResponse';

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await fetch(SlowestResponse);
    const jsonresponse = await result.json();
    setData([jsonresponse]);
  };
  fetchData();
  }, []);


  return (
      <CardContent>
        <Grid
          container
          justify="space-between"
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Typography
              className={classes.title}
              color="textSecondary"
              gutterBottom
              variant="body2"
            >
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="h3">
              <ul>
                {
                  data.map((item) => {
                    return <div>{item.maxTime}</div>
                  })
                }
              </ul>
            </Typography> 
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </CardContent>
  );
};

SlowestResponse.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string
};

export default SlowestResponse;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export your React hook logic in a custom hook and reuse it.
Since you only use `data` you will only need to return its value from your hook.

Here is an example:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const useApi = () => {
  const SlowestResponse = 'http://localhost:8080/api/SlowestResponse';

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(SlowestResponse);
      const jsonresponse = await result.json();
      setData([jsonresponse]);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return data;
}

const SlowestResponse = props => {
  const {
    className,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const data = useApi()

  return (<CardContent>
    <Grid container="container" justify="space-between">
      <Grid item="item">
        <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom="gutterBottom" variant="body2"></Typography>
        <Typography variant="h3">
          <ul>
            {
              data.map((item) => {
                return <div>{item.maxTime}</div>
              })
            }
          </ul>
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </CardContent>);
};

SlowestResponse.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string
};

export default SlowestResponse;
```

You can export `useApi` in an external file and import it in each component file that needs it.

Comment: Yes, that is right. But it involves cancelling fetch requests on unmount, that is out of the scope of the question. But I can add that to the answer, if needed.

Comment: BTW, there is no error handling neither in the author's code

Comment: @HMR https://fr.reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: *The solution in #14369 (comment) is usually the right one. (Or preferably you'd cancel the async work you're doing.)*

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-react-webpack-2s2ny) is an example of checking if component is mounted before setting state and an example of the race condition when you want to cancel based on last user input. In most cases you don't need to cancel a fetch request but just not try and set the result when unmounted. The anti pattern is when you would add an event listener and only check if mounted when the listener is invoked (like window onscroll). It would be better in that case to remove listener on unmount (or cleanup function in hooks).